# change get_the_term_list separator Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress child theme development.. I want to change the separator that is created from  `get_the_term_list()` function .. I'm using it on single post like this

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'artista', '', ' Ft ' ); ?>
```

I want to change it so it only uses one 'Ft' for the first tag, and then uses the symbol '&' for remaining tags

Example: Name1 Ft Name2 & Name3 (if there are more tags it should only use '&' and for first tag it should use Ft)

Comment: After fetching result, try something like this as I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fetch the elements, Why don't you try something like this to figure out.

```
$string = 'name & NAme & NAme & Name';
if($string){
$stringExplode = explode(' & ', $string);
    if($stringExplode){
            $appendFt = $stringExplode[0]. ' FT ';
            $stringExplode[0] = $appendFt;
    }
    $shift = array_shift($stringExplode);
    $stringImplode = implode(' & ', $stringExplode);

}
echo $shift.$stringImplode;
```

Comment: THanks that helped me!